# PowerShell Remoting, Second hop and delegation

Tags: powershell, kerberos-delegation

I am looking for the most secure way to implement WinRM in situations where Second hop comes up. Specifically I want to run a script from an arbitrary but singular management machine, and initiate remote sessions on all workstations, using passed credentials of a single specific management user. Those remote sessions there need to be able to second hop to specific shares on a file server, to access the appropriate resources.
I know CredSSD is pretty weak, so I am looking for something better. Richard Siddaway mentions "AD based delegation" [here](https://blogs.msmvps.com/richardsiddaway/2017/10/31/powershell-v6-2-remoting/), but the best information I have found about Delegation is from MS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-5.1), and all the delegation options say "Does not support the second hop for WinRM". So, IS there a secure way to enable Second Hopping, for a single specified user or group, via Active Directory? Ideally I would love to limit second hop to JUST the specified third server/share, and only for the specified user or group. So, any remote session using different credentials can't second hop, and the correct credentials can't second hop to other resources. Is that even remotely doable?

Comment: i think yes; it can be done..

Answer (score 1):

It's apparent you have been looking into this, yet, have you seen to below approaches to ascertain if they can get you to your goal?

> PowerShell Remoting Kerberos Double Hop Solved Securely
>
> Are you facing issues with PowerShell remoting and credentials? You
>   remote into your jump box, but then any remoting beyond there gets a
>   big red ACCESS DENIED. Maybe you’ve tried CredSSP, but people say that
>   isn’t safe. Read today’s post for a completely legit, secure, safe,
>   and easy way to enable Kerberos double hop for PowerShell remoting.
>
> https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/08/30/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely
>
> Another solution to multi-hop PowerShell remoting
>
> I've discovered another solutions for the problem of two hops in the
>   PowerShell remoting, that I haven't seen anywhere in my searches on
>   the Internet. I'm sure that some people know about it but it doesn't
>   seem to be widely known.
>
> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sergey_babkins_blog/2015/03/18/another-solution-to-multi-hop-powershell-remoting

***Update to your last comment***

This...

> most secure way to implement WinRM

... and this...

> My hope is to find a solution that an overprotective/paranoid IT
>   Manager can still sign off on. If my understanding is wrong I would love to be educated.

It can really be a matter of opinion. Meaning, what is secure enough for one is not for another.

So, that first must be fleshed out before you can say yey or ney to any option.

- Does one mean end to risk management/security of the pipe between source to destination? (so host to host mutual auth, SSL, SDI-server
  and domain isolation, etc.)
- Does one mean, security the data moving through the pipe? Encrypting
  at the source, decrypting on the destination, or obfuscating code?

Some, I will say WinRM is inherently insecure since it defaults to HTTP. Most networks are not leveraging mutual auth internally, RBAC for specific functions/operations/connections, [SDI](https://www.bing.com/search?q=windows%20domain%20and%20server%20isolation&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=windows%20domain%20and%20server%20isolation&sc=1-35&sk=&cvid=E20D02AFB07341218D069E6BA1731B6C), etc.  [There are many articles on WinRM security](https://www.bing.com/search?q=securing%20winrm&form=ANNTH1&refig=b4ee626083b545a786179fbf6049b751&sp=-1&pq=securing%20winrm&sc=2-14&qs=n&sk=&cvid=b4ee626083b545a786179fbf6049b751) as well as ones on options to address it.

Securing WinRM

> [WinRMSecurity - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://www.bing.com/search?q=securing%20winrm&form=ANNTH1&refig=b4ee626083b545a786179fbf6049b751&sp=-1&pq=securing%20winrm&sc=2-14&qs=n&sk=&cvid=b4ee626083b545a786179fbf6049b751)
>
> [Is WinRM Secure or do I need HTTPs?](https://foxdeploy.com/2017/02/08/is-winrm-secure-or-do-i-need-https)
>
> [How To: Configure WINRM for HTTPS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2019527/how-to-configure-winrm-for-https)
>
> [How To Secure Powershell Remoting In A Windows Domain](https://www.networkadm.in/securing-powershell)
>
> [PowerShell remoting over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7)

Then there is the use of JEA

> [Just Enough Administration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/jea/overview?view=powershell-7)
>
> [JEA Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/jea/prerequisites?view=powershell-7)
>
> [Using JEA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/jea/using-jea?view=powershell-7)
>
> [Auditing and Reporting on JEA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/jea/audit-and-report?view=powershell-7)
>
> [Improvements to Just Enough Administration (JEA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/wmf/whats-new/jea-improvements?view=powershell-7)

Risk Management/Security is all about layers and trade-offs. Cost, posture vs usability, DR, and maintenance of said deployment.

Comment: Interesting. As I read it, the "best" solution is the highlighted one at the bottom, and that one doesn't work with WinRM, which is what underlies PowerShell Remote jobs.
I did find that second link, but my initial reaction was that it's a bit of a kludge or workaround. My hope is to find a solution that an overprotective/paranoid IT Manager can still sign off on. If my understanding is wrong I would love to be educated.